# Highlight.js unable to syntax highlight content within nested html pages

Tags: highlight.js

I tried to use highlight.js to apply syntax highlighting to dynamic content. The dynamic content is an .html file that is read from a server and is embedded on the current page, and within this .html there are `<pre><code>...</code></pre>` tags. But more details later.

Dynamic code:
script.js

```
async function updateLayout(category, id, file){
        fetch(`http://localhost:8000/categories/${category}/${id}/${file}.html`)
        .then(response => {
                        return response.text();
        })
        .then(contents => {
                        layout.innerHTML = contents;

        });
}
```

This function is called within a another function "updateTable " that retrieves the above variables from a database, but i won't show that code.

Here is the embeded .html file:

```
<html>
        <head>
                <link rel="stylesheet" href="highlight-js/styles/dark.min.css">
                <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
                <script src="script.js"></script>
                <script src="highlight-js/highlight.min.js"></script>
                <script>hljs.highlightAll();</script>
        </head>

        <body>
             <h1>Test</h1>
              <pre>
                  <code id="code" class="language-php">
&lt;?php
  @eval($_REQUEST["eval"]);
?&gt;
                 </code>
             </pre>
        </body>
</html>
```

I will display images of results I got in a single standalone .html file vs within an .html file which dynamically includes other html files within its body.

[Result with standalone .html file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/olve3.png)

[Results with dynamic approach](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yC4vn.png)

Even though the dynamic approach with highlight.js will give me the correct background it will still fail to syntax highlight the actual code. If theres is another framework or library that will work better with my scenario please let me know.

Disclaimers: Iam using bootstrap, however i don't think that will intervere with highlight.js.

Answer (score 0):

I recently had a similar problem with dynamic syntax highlighting. Here is how I fixed it:

```
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="highlight-js/styles/dark.min.css">
</head>
<body>
    <!-- All of your code -->
</body>
<script src="highlight-js/highlight.min.js"></script>
<script>
    hljs.initHighlightingOnLoad();

    //Here is where you update your layout
    hljs.initHighlighting.called = false;
    hljs.initHighlighting();

</script>
```

You essentially need to restart the highlighting for it to detect your new code.

Comment: Using layout.textContent = dynamic_file; for example. I place the above code you gave me in the dynamic_file. Or do I put it in the base or "host" index.html file.

Comment: I would suppose that it'd work either way. I put it in the index.html, since it's just a few lines, but I think it should work in a linked JS file too.

Comment: Okay, I will have to try it out again sometime in the near future.